# Store Notification Small Icon in Database from NotificationListenerService

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a NotificationListenerService that intercepts all incoming notifications and records the information in a SQLite database. The only issue I'm running into is how to get the status bar icon aka small icon.

`notification.icon` has been deprecated since API 23, and `extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON)` has been deprecated since API 26.

Up until Android 10 (API 29), `extras.getInt("android.icon")` has worked fine, but now that returns 0 for every notification, despite it interestingly (as far as I can tell) being the same as `extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON)`.

I know it's recommended to use `getSmallIcon()` now, but how can I store this in a database? In the past, I've been able to get the resource id from the above methods, but `getSmallIcon()` returns an Icon object. I know I can convert this to a Drawable, or a Bitmap, but how can I get the resource id of an object I don't know the name of? And from another app, nonetheless.

Note: I know there's a method of `getSmallIcon()` called `getResId()`, but the call requires API 28, an API higher than I'd like to have as my minimum.

Am I doing this right? Is there a better way to do this that I can't find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution for anyone who finds this in the future:

```
int iconResId = 0;

// if the API is P or above, this is easy
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    iconResId = notificationSmallIcon.getResId();
}

// in case the getResId doesn't work, or the API is below P
if (iconResId == 0) {

    /* first try to get it from the small icon
        if the icon is from a resource, then the toString() method will contain the resource id, 
        but masked to a hex value, so we need to get it back to its integer value
     */
    final String smallIconString = notificationSmallIcon.toString();
    if (smallIconString.contains("id=")) {
        final String iconHexId = smallIconString.substring(smallIconString.indexOf("id=") + 5).replace(")", "");
        iconResId = Integer.parseInt(iconHexId, 16);
    }

    /* if still zero, above method didn't work, use the deprecated method as I've found it to still
        be reliable despite it, you know, being deprecated since API 23
     */
    if (iconResId == 0) {
        iconResId = notification.icon;
    }

}

// if still zero now, either there's no icon, or none of the above methods work anymore
```